# RcppShark Random Forest example throws exception about the random number generator

Tags: c++, r, machine-learning, random-forest, shark-ml

I followed this example:

https://www.2021.ai/randsharkmachinelearning/

when running this command on R:

```
sharkFit <- SharkRFTrain(X, Y, nTrees = 100)
```

I get:

```
Error in SharkRFTrain(X, Y, nTrees = 100) : 
  Should not call this. Fix the random numbers generator if you need this. 478
```

This exception is thrown from this "cpp" line:

```
trainer.train(model, trainData);
```

I suspect the reason is written here:

https://github.com/aydindemircioglu/RcppShark#notes

> The random number generator was replaced, as R packages must use the random generator from R and not the C/C++ internal one. Thereffore, a direct comparison of results of algorithms that depend on (pseudo) random numbers cannot be done.

Is there a way to mitigate this?

tried both R versions: 3.4.1, 3.3.2

Comment: Over at github the question came up how important the random forest feature from shark is for you. The current  implementation seems to have some fundamental problem with a new one under way. Are you interested in Shark's random forest in particular, or are you trying to learn about integrating Shark into R in general? Feel free to comment here or join the discussion on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have investigated this and was able to narrow it down to some degree:

- The error message is produced here: https://github.com/aydindemircioglu/RcppShark/blob/master/src/shark/Rng/Runif.h#L71
- The calling code is here: https://github.com/aydindemircioglu/RcppShark/blob/master/src/src/Algorithms/RFTrainer.cpp#L178

Since I was not able to fix it, I have opened an issue here: https://github.com/aydindemircioglu/RcppShark/issues/1